# div click under anchor tag not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wTy93/1/)

Here a child div inside anchor tag, how to get click event of child div, for example if user click on div having class `.press_me`  alert msg get display , and if user click anywhere on main div it should redirect to respective anchor link

HTML :

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.in"><div class="dv_child"> America <div class="press_me">click me</div></div></a>
 <a href="https://www.google.co.in" target="_blank"><div class="dv_child"> India <div class="press_me">click me</div></div></a>
<a href="https://www.google.co.in" target="_blank"><div class="dv_child"> Russia <div class="press_me">click me</div></div></a>
<a href="https://www.google.co.in" target="_blank"><div class="dv_child"> Germany <div class="press_me">click me</div></div></a>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".press_me").on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).parent().html());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.preventDefault` it stops the default action

```
$(".press_me").on('click', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).parent().html());
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wTy93/6/)

Comment: your answer was perfect, after alert msg it should not redirect to link thats what i want, thanks man

Answer (score 6):

USe `$(this)` instead of `$this`.
Also you can use `event.stopPropagation()` to stop propagating the child click to parent.

In your case you just need to prevent the default behaviour of anchor tag. For that, use `event.preventDefault()`

```
$(".press_me").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    alert($(this).parent().html());
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wTy93/8/)

Comment: thanks its solved with both answer btw difference between event.preventDefault(); and event.stopPropagation()

Comment: preventDefault() prevents the browser from going to the given link.


stopPropagation() prevents the parent elements from receiving the event (in this case, it's the click event). For additional detail, please go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 0):

Also you will have to update first element anchor:

**HTML**

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.in" target="_blank"><div class="dv_child_1"> America <div class="press_me">click me</div></div></a>

<a href="https://www.google.co.in" target="_blank"><div class="dv_child_1"> India <div class="press_me">click me</div></div></a>

<a href="https://www.google.co.in" target="_blank"><div class="dv_child_1"> Russia <div class="press_me">click me</div></div></a>

<a href="https://www.google.co.in" target="_blank"><div class="dv_child_1"> Germany <div class="press_me">click me</div></div></a>
```

**JS** (Same as already suggested)

```
$(".press_me").on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).parent().html());
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wTy93/7/)**

Comment: thanks for reply, but this will not solved , if user click  .press_me  then anchor tag should not to be works

Comment: @j809 you missing function(event) event.preventDefault();..?